# Returning to Flex after PayPal Express Checkout payment

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, paypal

I have successfully integrated PayPal Express into a Flex application.  In DoExpressCheckoutPayment.php, I have the following JavaScript line of code that will not execute:

```
window.opener.window.document.getElementById('index').paymentComplete();
```

'index' - http://mysite.com/index.html# contains index.swf
'paymentComplete()' - the function that finishes processing the transaction

Has anyone successfully activated callback methods back from a popup to a Flex application using JavaScript?

Thank you in advance for any help,

Orville

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Flex, the address in URLRequest was absolute (http://mysite.com/phpfolder/) and not relative (/phpfolder) to the SWF.  For some reason JavaScript requires the relative URL for the following line to work.  I am not sure why.

```
window.opener.window.document.getElementById('index').paymentComplete();
```

Answer (score 0):

[SWFAddress](http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/) would be a really good solution for this.

Comment: I did not see anything there related to my problem.  I probably did not explain the scenario well enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the popup to call a JS method in the html page that holds the flex app, you can use [addCallBack](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback%28%29) method of the `ExternalInterface` class to make that JS method communicate with the flex app.

Answer (score 0):

for getElementById use the id from the EMBED-tag in the OBJECT-tag .. not the id from the OBJECT-tag itself!